# Set location of an object as same as cursor postion in visual c#

Tags: c#, position

Well ,I'm trying to make my button location as same as cursor position when the mouse left button is down so i write this :

```
private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    button1.Location = Cursor.Position;
}
```

But the button moves so far than the position of cursor, also it occurs only once and I can't move button freely with the mouse.
What is the problem?

Comment: I don't think that the `MouseEventArgs` coordinates are the same as the `button1.Location` coordinates, you might have to translate.

Comment: do you want to drag the button1 after pressing left mouse ?

Comment: @reg yes that's what i want

Comment: ok, then simple [down] - {flag} - [move] - [up] - !{flag} ... wait my sample

Comment: @Black-Hole my sample not work or what's the problem ?

Comment: @reg sorry for delay...
no it's not working and i also don't know where to put these codes?
can you post a full code?

Comment: @Black-Hole it's a full code :) also you can put this logic from MouseMove/MouseDown/MouseUp with standard Visual-Designer (if you use MS VisualStudio) 
or create the any logic-layer for basic initialisation on different form-components. /wait minute for new sample

Comment: @Black-Hole if your problem resolved, you can accept this answer for 'close' your question and voteup my answer if that sample was helpful..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

illustrate my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24410717/set-location-of-an-object-as-same-as-cursor-postion-in-visual-c-sharp#comment37770478_24410717):

```
private bool _isAllowMove = false;
...

button1.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler((object sender, MouseEventArgs e) => 
{
    if(!_isAllowMove) {
        return;
    }
    button1.Location = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
});

button1.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler((object sender, MouseEventArgs e) => 
{
    _isAllowMove = true;
});

button1.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler((object sender, MouseEventArgs e) => 
{
    _isAllowMove = false;
});
```

---

// other full example for new [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24410717/set-location-of-an-object-as-same-as-cursor-postion-in-visual-c-sharp#comment37863411_24410717)

Dynamically set events for all buttons:

```
public partial class Form1: Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //...
        setHandler(button1);
        setHandler(button2);
        //...
    }

    protected void setHandler(Button btn)
    {
        // TODO: synchronise thread & remove old handler
        /**
         * e.g.:
         * lock(_eLock){
         *   btn.MouseMove -= new MouseEventHandler(..)
         *   btn.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(..)
         * }
         * 
         */

        // NOTE: the 'AllowDrop' property only for example - 
        //       you can replace this with your custom components - e.g. ButtonCustom()
        /**
         * public class ButtonCustom: Button
         * {
         *    ...
         *    bool AllowMove { get; set; }
         *    ...
         * }
         * 
         */

        btn.AllowDrop = false;

        btn.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler((object sender, MouseEventArgs e) => {
            if(!btn.AllowDrop) {
                return;
            }
            btn.Location = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        });

        btn.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler((object sender, MouseEventArgs e) => {
            btn.AllowDrop = true;
        });

        btn.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler((object sender, MouseEventArgs e) => {
            btn.AllowDrop = false;
        });
    }
}
```